# firebase firestore gives error for a project that's been added to firebase projects

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I've added my project to firestore and I'm doing firestore google auth just fine.
My problem is firebase firestore.
It just doesn't work and I have no idea why.
I'm trying to do a simple add before doing the actual process for my app and it doesn't work.
[image]
here I implemented a simple function to add a user and then called it, doing it all in build function.
I get this in my console:
[image]

p.s.
"adding user" is printed on console.

p.s.
I do have the firebase_options.dart file.

Comment: Did you checked your firebase rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These thing are you sure that the correct:
1.Using correct google_services.json file
2.Edit Fire store rules if you are not using authorization

You have to manually whitelist your existing Google OAuth 2.0 client IDs in the Firebase console before using it with the new Auth APIs.

In order to do so, follow these steps:

1. Go to the Credentials section in the Google API Console.
2. Select from the top right corner the project where you had previously configured Google Sign-In.
3. Go to the OAuth 2.0 client IDs section

If you are using Google Sign-In on Android or iOS applications:

4. Take note of the Client ID string corresponding to all the entries registered for your applications.
5. Input these Client IDs into your Firebase project’s configuration:

Go to the Firebase console at https://console.firebase.google.com

Open the Auth section

Under Sign-In methods, open the Google configuration, and add there all you client IDs, to the whitelist of client IDs from external projects.

If you are using Google Sign-In on a web application:

Click to open your web client ID and take note of both the client ID and secret.

Input this Client ID into your Firebase project’s configuration:

Go to the Firebase console at https://console.firebase.google.com

Open the Auth section

Under Sign-In methods, open the Google configuration, and add the values under the Web SDK configuration section.

Comment: @Kamand Shayegan Please let us know if the above answer helps you.